# Is there a VB script or a bat file that I can run to list all DSN's on a machine?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, odbc, dsn

What I am looking for is a simple vb script that can run and return a list of all the DSN's or ODBC connections on the local machine.

Comment: Are you interested in a VB.NET solution, or did you select that tag by mistake?  VB.NET is not the same as VBScript nor VBA.

Comment: i'm sorry i meant to choose vbscript.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need to do:

```
   for /f %%a in ('reg query HKLM\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI') do echo %%~na
   pause
```

Comment: running that in a batch file pops up a cmd window that instantly closes. any ideas?

Comment: just add a pause at the end